# neo4j- filter duplicates regardless of order

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

Consider the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:TWEETED]->(tweet:Tweet)<-[:TWEETED]-(p2:Person)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name
```

This query returns the following results:

```
╒══════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════╕
│"p1.name"                 │"p2.name"                 │
╞══════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│"john"                    │"bob"                     │
├──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│"bob"                     │"john"                    │
├──────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
.....
```

I'll be better with getting only one of the results, regardless of the `direction/order`. How can I filter the result to remove these duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a restriction on the graph id() of both nodes to filter out the duplicates:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:TWEETED]->(tweet:Tweet)<-[:TWEETED]-(p2:Person)
WHERE id(p1) < id(p2)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name
```